# Conceptual questions about map reduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, distributed-computing

I've been doing a lot of reading about Map Reduce and I had the following questions that I can't seem to find the answers to:

1. Everyone points to the word-count example. But why do we need the map reduce paradigm for a really big corpus for the word counts? I'm not sure how having one machine read from a really huge stream and maintain the word counts all in memory is worse than having a number of connected machines split the counting task amongst themselves and aggregate it again. Finally, at the end, there will still be one place where all the count will be maintained right?
2. Are mapper and reducer machines physically different? Or can the mapping and reducing happen on the same machine?
3. Suppose my stream is the foll three sentences:

   > ```
   > a b c
   > b c d
   > b c
   > ```
   >
   > So, the word-count mapper will generate key-value pairs as:

> ```
> a 1
> b 1
> c 1
> b 1
> c 1
> d 1
> b 1
> c 1
> ```
>
> And now it will pass these key value pairs to the next stage, right? I have the following questions:
>   - Is this next stage the reducer?
>   - Can a mapper send the first b 1 and second b 1 tuples to different nodes? If yes, then do the counts get aggregated in the next phase? If no, then why not? Wouldn't that be counter intutive?

1. Finally, in the end of a map reduce job, the final output is all aggregated at a single machine, right? If yes, doesn't this make the entire process too expensive, computationally?

Answer (score 0):

1. Word count is easiest to explain that is why you see it more often. It has become "Hello World" example for Hadoop Framework.
2. Yes, Map and Reduce can be on same machine or different machine. Reduce starts only after all map completes.
3. All keys goes to same reducer.
   ( so answer to your question 
   Can a mapper send the first b 1 and second b 1 tuples to different nodes --- is NO )

Also its not right to say entire processing is expensive.
As Map-Reduce paradigm can process/solve/analyze problems which were almost impossible to be processed by single machine ( the reason its called BIG data ).
And now with MapReduce its possible with commodity ( read cheaper ) hardware ; that is why is widely accepted.

Answer (score 0):

The Map-Reduce (MR) paradigm was created by Google, and Google is doing Word Count (or in their special case they are creating inverted indices, but that is pretty similar conceptually). You can use MR for many things (and people try doing it) but it isn't really useful. In fact many companies use MR for a special version of Word Count. When Spotify analyses their logs and reports which songs were listened to how often, it is basically word count, just with TB of logs.

The end-result doesn't land on only one machine in hadoop, but again in HDFS, which is distributed. And than you can perform another MR algorithm on that result, ...

In hadoop you have different kind of nodes, but as far as we have tested MR, all nodes where storing data as well as performing Map and Reduce jobs. The reason for performing the Map and Reduce jobs directly on the machine where data is stored is the locality and therefore lower network traffic. You can afterwards combine the reduced results and reduce them again.

For instance when Machine 1 has

> a b c

and Machine 2 has

> b c d
>
> b c

Than Machine 2 would Map and Reduce the data and only send

> b 2
>
> c 2
>
> d 1

over the wire. However Machine 2 actually wouldn't send the data anywhere, this result would rather be save as a preliminary result in HDFS and other machines can access it.

This was now specific to Hadoop, I think it helps to understand the Map-Reduce paradigm when you also look at other usage scenarios. The NoSQL Databases [Couchbase](http://www.couchbase.com/wiki/display/couchbase/Home) and [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) use Map-Reduce to create views. This means that you can analyse data and compute sums, min, max, counts, ... This MR-Jobs are run on all the nodes of such a database cluster and the results are stored in the database again and all of this without Hadoop and HDFS.